# почему два списка не равны?

Tags: python

попался в тестах подобный код:

```
t = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
t.keys()==t.values()
```

В результате выполнения получаем результат False, но почему так происходит, ведь мы сравниваем 2 одинаковых списка [1,2,3] и [1,2,3]?

Comment: Не факт, что списки одинаковы. Насколько я помню, порядок значений в t.keys() не гарантирован. Попробуйте упорядочить списки перед сравнением

Comment: @Pavel: порядок keys() совпадает с порядком values() в Питоне (какой бы это порядок ни был)

Comment: @jfs потому что это представления, если мне не изменяет память?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev: относительный порядок гарантируется языком (и когда эти функции списки возвращали, и когда dictview).

Comment: можно `all(a == b for a, b in t.items())` или `all(map(operator.eq, t.keys(), t.values()))` для сравнения ключей с соответствующими значениями в словаре написать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Python 3 вы сравниваете не списки. И даже не одинаковые типы. В Python3 метод `keys` возвращает тип `dict_keys`, а метод `values` тип `dict_values`.

Comment: [это от версии зависит](https://ideone.com/4VoS3n). На Питоне 2 эти функции возвращают списки. Учитывая, что у вопроса нет явной метки версии языка, то это стоит упомянуть.

Answer (score 1):

Зато если явно привести к списку, то всё получится:

```
t = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
list(t.keys())==list(t.values())
```

В результате имеем:

```
True
```